# Weird facebook like button on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On my site, I tried to implement the like button but it seems that whenever I point the button to my FB Page,the button simply disappears on IE and Firefox(works fine in Chrome). 
But when I point the button to any other FB page, the button just works fine.
Really drove me crazy.

My site: www.avozz.com

Button pointing to my FB Page

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/avozz" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Button pointing example to other FB Pages that works fine

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/PeterJacksonNZ" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/ClarifyWearableTextileArt" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/Starbucks" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0):

trying to solve by using the url [linter][1]

[1]: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.avozz.com/ and putting the appropriate meta tags on the header .....

or by putting the button in iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:30px;" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.avozz.com%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried using iframe and fix the meta tag, same thing still happening. The Like button disappears when I link the button to my www.facebook.com/avozz. But it is okay when I put other FB page into the link.  :(